# How to search ButtonText using Searchview?

Tags: java, android, button, search, searchview

I have square Buttons(3x20).I want to dynamically search for text on buttons using Searchview.I've checked many places, but Listview has always been added to the xml file. I don't have a chance to do this.When I search, I want the buttons that do not contain the letter I searched for disappear.[image]